# Doxygen - declare parameter as optional

Tags: c++, parameters, doxygen, optional-parameters

I am documenting a codebase using Doxygen and was wondering if there is a keyword for declaring an argument to a function to be optional.  Something like:

```
/*!
\fn int add(int a, int b=0)
\brief adds two values
\param a the first operand
\param \optional b the second operand.  Default is 0
\return the result
*/
```

It seems like this is something that should exist, but I haven't been able to find it anywhere.  Is there an actual option, or do I just need to make note in the description?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To answer your question: No, there is no such thing.

But I don't share your opinion that there should be something like that. After all, the function declaration will be displayed together with its documentation, so everybody can see that `b` is optional and what it's default argument is. And for the `\fn` see doxygen's documentation [discouraging the use of \fn](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdfn).

Comment: good to know.  what should I use in place of `\fn` for global functions?

Comment: Nothing - just place the documenting comment right before the function(-declaration), like the link I posted says (first paragraph)

Answer (score 1):

I cheat and use `\param foo [in,out,opt,banana] Describe what foo is for.`

You can add *any* options!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not provided by Doxygen - you will have to manually make a note of it in the description.