# How to cause Doxygen to show default template arguments

Tags: c++, doxygen

Consider:

```
// In temp.cpp
#include "a.h"

template <typename T>
struct A {};

/// Main
int main() {
    return 0;
}


// In a.h
/// My template
/// \tparam T The meaning of T
template <typename T = MY_SYMBOL>
struct A;
```

For some reason, `MY_SYMBOL` does not appear in the documentation of `A`. How can I cause it to appear?

P.S.: The default template argument does appear if I put it with the definition instead of the declaration. However, I do need it with the forward declaration...

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261136/doxygen-declare-parameter-as-optional

Comment: I haven't used Doxygen much for about a year but template support was pretty bad then. Not picking up default template arguments doesn't surprise me becauae it's a fairly new feature of C++.

Comment: @tukra May I ask what you use now?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Ha. Doxygen still, just haven't looked closely at the output or updated for a while.

Comment: I would try looking into using CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING. From the documentation:

    If the CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING tag is set to YES then doxygen will use the clang parser for more accurate parsing at the cost of reduced performance. This can be particularly helpful with template rich C++ code for which doxygen's built-in parser lacks the necessary type information.